# Asp.Net Web API 2: How to get data binding to use the correct data type in a controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

In a nutshell, I have two classes and two derived classes.  The derived class has a collection that hides the parent class.  Even though the Controller method has the parent data type for the parameter, Web API 2 creates a derived data type for the parameter and puts the `Items` sent up by the client in to the hidden `Items` collection.

How would I code this correctly to send in data that looks like the derived class but access it as the parent class data type or am I doing the `new` keyword incorrectly?  The parent classes represent the database tables.  The derived classes fill-in supporting data about the products in the shopping cart.  I guess I could create two different Controller methods and overload them, but I am curious none the less on how to do this properly.

I have the following classes:

```
ShoppingListVM {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ICollection<ShoppingListItemVM> Items {get;set;}
}
ShoppingListItemVM {
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

And derived classes:

```
ShoppingListExpandedVM : ShoppingListVM {
    new public ICollection<ShoppingListItemExpanded> Items {get;set;}
}
ShoppingListItemExpandedVM : ShoppingListItemVM {
    public string Name {get;set;}  // Additional fields beyond ShoppingListItemVM above
}
```

The Controller method looks like this, specifically receiving a `ShoppingListVM` data type.

```
public ShoppingListExpandedVM ShoppingListSave([FromBody] ShoppingListVM shoppingList) {
    var myShoppingList = ShoppingListVM.Map( shoppingList);
    _shoppingListService.Save( myShoppingList);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I send in data that has the fields of `ShoppingListExpandedVM` with `Items` having the fields of `ShoppingListItemExpandedVM`.  The Controller parameter `ShoppingListVM shoppingList` shows data properly except for the nested `Items` which is null.  The debugger shows two `Items` arrays where the `ShoppingListItemExpandedVM` data type is populated and the `ShoppingListItemVM` data type is empty.

Comment: "*Even though the Controller method has the parent data type for the parameter, Web API 2 creates a derived data type for the parameter*" I am a bit confused because this is not possible / at least I can't do that with my local example. Do you have custom model binder? or custom JSON serializer?

Comment: @weichch Nope, nothing special. In fact we just created the project a month ago in VS 2017. In the debugger, you can see the data types are the derived types. I would not think it is possible either.

Comment: @weichch I ended up having to create two controller methods with overloaded signatures.

Comment: Glad to see you resolved this. I still don't know how was that derived model created without a model binder.

Comment: The controller is only going to create the object that you tell it to expect and attempt to populate the properties from the request data. It won't hunt around looking for other classes which may or may not have other properties that are contained in the body. Taking a different point of view though, if the extended versions of the classes just contain extra fields, then you could merge them, or on your method always expect the extended version. If the request does not contain the extended properties, they just won't be set.